# Change cannot be merged due to unsatisfiable dependencies git

Tags: git, github, merge, gerrit

Am new to git and gerrit. And am getting below error as merge is failing.

```
    Change cannot be merged due to unsatisfiable dependencies.
The following dependency errors were found:
Depends on patch set 2 of I5d113cf4, however the current patch set is 3.
Please rebase the change and upload a replacement commit.
```

Below are the steps i have done. All these happened with 1 month time

1. Committed a change for the repo( change id is I5d113cf4). Did three amends on the same id. Third amend says published edit on patch set 2 and later have abandoned it 5 days later.
2. Before abandon or merge of above change ID, I have Committed change for the same repo with a different change id and amended 11 times.  Abandon time of above ID(I5d113cf4) and third patch set of this ID is with 1 min difference. Now am satisfied with the review, tried to merge the code. But facing the above mentioned issue.

Am already on the 11 amend of new change id and want to merge. But it is throwing issue for the abandoned ID and not merging the code. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You have to **update your local repository** before to be able to push to Gerrit.

Try to update it localy using the command `git pull --rebase`.
If you still have error, please add a picture of your local git history pointing which commit you have trouble with.

Comment: i did that. And it says **Current branch master is up to date**

Comment: Does the change id I5d113cf4 is yours ? This change is not pushed under gerrit I guees

Comment: Did you abandonned it both on github/gerrit server and on your repository ? Is it possible to have a picture of your local history and review server (Gerrit) ?